Question Description: Regarding data retrieval and operations on the Solana blockchain, I have the following technical queries requiring assistance:
Additional Note:
I am willing to provide compensation for detailed technical insights or script implementations. Preferably, I would like practical code references or specific solutions.

How to retrieve all Swap transaction details?
Objective: Parse Swap-related data for a specific account (e.g., Swap transactions on Orca or Serum) and calculate the following:
•  Quantity of purchased tokens (e.g., a specific token)
•  Cost in SOL for the purchase
•  Quantity of sold tokens (e.g., a specific token)
•  Revenue in SOL from the sale
I understand this might involve parsing transaction logs or event details but lack clarity on the exact steps, including the tools or APIs to use.
How to query balances?
•  Query the balance of the native currency (SOL)
•  Query the balance of a specified SPL Token
The goal is to efficiently fetch real-time balance data for an account via smart contract or RPC.
How to transfer native currency (SOL) and SPL Tokens?
This includes standard implementations for SOL transfers (via System Program) and SPL Token transfers. I would like to understand:
•  The required parameters (e.g., accounts, public keys, private keys)
•  The most convenient libraries or tools to accomplish this.

